# How to disable parallax wagerfield on small resolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, parallax.js

I use this [parallax](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax), but can't disable it on mobile?

I found some methods like this:

```
scene = $('#scene').parallax();
scene.parallax('disable');
```

But it didn't work. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable parallax straight after it's been initialized you should wrap your `scene.parallax('disable');` in a `setTimeout` function. If you look at the source code of Parallax.js you will see that there's `supportDelay: 500` value which is used as an argument in `enable` function. According to that your code for disabling would look like this:

```
var scene = $('#scene').parallax();
setTimeout(function () {
  scene.parallax('disable');
}, 500);
```

**Update:**
Just found [an article](http://www.stefankaltenegger.com/playground/adding-breakpoints-parallax-js/) that explains different perspective on disabling parallax.js on small devices.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather go in different direction. Instead of making something disable on small screens make it working only on larger devices:

```
if ($(window).width() > 640) { //set up breaking point

    $('#scene').parallax(); // this or any other code you need

}
```